# Nesting git repositories with .gitignore

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have three repositories: `first`, `second`, and `third` one inside another with a structure like this:

```
first
    .git
    .gitignore <- second/
    firstrepofiles
    second
        .git
        .gitignore <- third/
        secondrepofiles
        third
            .git
            thirdrepofiles
```

The purpose of such structure is to separate parts of the system, yet keep them connected and continuously integrated.

It seems to work just fine but I wonder is it a bad practice to do something like that?

Answer (score 1):

It would be cleaner to do this using git submodules. (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

To do this, just add repo 2 and repo 3 as submodules.

Comment: Will a user who has access to say `third` submodule be able to access `first` or `second` submodule?

Comment: No not automatically. Since they are seperate repos.